# Is the vector $\langle 0,0,0\rangle$ a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$? And is its Spanning set a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

The way I am thinking, $\langle 0,0,0 \rangle$ can't be a spanning set, right? You can't multiply it by anything to span the entirety of $\mathbb R^3$? 
However, I am fairly new to these concepts and am very confused, so I'd love some proper explanation on if my thoughts are correct and how to *actually* figure out a problem such as this one.

Comment: The set containing only the zero vector (i.e. additive identity) of any vector space is always a valid subspace.

Comment: Is this also true if I have a larger vector? Such as {<0,0,0>, <1,0,0>}? Does the fact that the zero vector appears make it a valid subspace?

Comment: No, $\{ \langle 0,0,0 \rangle, \langle 1,0,0 \rangle\}$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$.  Subspaces are vector spaces in and of themselves, and as such are closed under linear combinations (i.e. vector addition and scalar multiplication). The set $\{ \langle 0,0,0 \rangle, \langle 1,0,0 \rangle\}$ is not a valid vector space since the linear combinations of $\langle 1,0,0 \rangle$ are not in the set (that is, the vectors $ c\, \langle 1,0,0 \rangle$ are not in the set, where $c$ is any scalar).

Comment: The vector $(0,0,0)$ is not a subspace; the one-element set $\{(0,0,0)\}$ is and its only basis is the empty set.

Answer (score 0):

The vector $\langle 0,0,0 \rangle$ is trivially a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

But its spanning set is not all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. The spanning set is the set of vectors that can be expressed as a linear combination of $\langle 0, 0, 0 \rangle$, which as you've pointed out, is solely the vector $\langle 0,0,0 \rangle$ since multiplying the vector with anything yields $0$.